# Swift Error: Can't invoke (..) with an argument list of type (([String) -> (Int, String))

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to create an Array extension that transforms an array into a Dictionary with generic Key/Value types.

This is my code:

```
extension Array  {
    func transformToDictionary<K: Hashable, V>(@noescape mappingFunction: (Array.Generator.Element) -> (K, V)) -> [K: V] {
        var dict: [K: V] = [:]
        for el in self {
            let result = mappingFunction(el)
            dict[result.0] = result.1
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

This works for some cases like:

```
let stringArray = ["String1", "String2"]
stringArray.transformToDictionary({ (element: String) -> (Int, String) in
    return (element.hashValue, element)
})
```

But doesn't work in another case like:

```
let nestedStringArray = [["String1"], ["String2"]]
stringArray.transformToDictionary({ (element: [String]) -> (Int, String) in
     return (element.first!.hashValue, element.first!)
})
```

This will lead to a compiler error saying:

> Can't invoke 'transformToDictionary' with an argument list of type
>   (([String) -> (Int, String))

Did I do anything wrong here or is this a Swift compiler bug?

Answer (score 1):

In your second case you're trying to perform the nested array operation on the stringArray object. Change stringArray to nestedStringArray here and it should work (at least it did in my Playground):

```
let nestedStringArray = [["String1"], ["String2"]]
nestedStringArray.transformToDictionary({ (element: [String]) -> (Int, String) in
     return (element.first!.hashValue, element.first!)
})
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo. But performing the function on the nested array still results in the same error

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using? This works ok for me under Xcode 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

First let's inspect the first example:

```
let stringArray = ["String1", "String2"]
stringArray.transformToDictionary({ (element: String) -> (Int, String) in
    return (element.hashValue, element)
})
```

`stringArray` is an `Array` of `String` objects and the `transformToDictionary` method expects a `String` (`element`) and returns a tuple of `Int` and `String`. This works as you have pointed out.

Now take the second example:

```
let nestedStringArray = [["String1"], ["String2"]]
stringArray.transformToDictionary({ (element: [String]) -> (Int, String) in
    return (element.first!.hashValue, element.first!)
})
```

The `nestedStringArray` is not used and the `transformToDictionary` method is actually being called on `stringArray`.

If we fix that:

```
let nestedStringArray = [["String1"], ["String2"]]
nestedStringArray.transformToDictionary({ (element: [String]) -> (Int, String) in
    return (element.first!.hashValue, element.first!)
})
```

We will still get the error you mentioned:

> > Cannot invoke 'transformToDictionary' with an argument list of type '(([String]) -> (Int, String))'

The reason for this is that the 2nd item in the returned tuple is a `String`, but the input value is a string array (`[String]`).

This usage will work with an array of strings:

```
let nestedStringArray = [["String1"], ["String2"]]
nestedStringArray.transformToDictionary({ (element: [String]) -> (Int, [String]) in
    return (0, element)
})
```

Comment: The nested example specifies the first element of the array, so you won't get the error as you described and don't need to change the return type to an Array.